# Looping through stream data

Tags: c#, loops

I'm writing a program that uses a fingerprint reader. I have stored the fingerprint data in an array [arr]. Unfortunately, only the first value is read i.e [0]. So only one finger is detected and the rest are ignored but if I place a specific number in the array e.g 2. It works fine for that value alone:

Here's my code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < (arr.Length - 1); x++)
        {
            byte[] fpbyte = GetStringToBytes(arr[x]);
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(fpbyte);
            Data.Templates[x] = new DPFP.Template(stream);
        }
        foreach (DPFP.Template template in Data.Templates)
        {
            // Get template from storage.
            if (template != null)
            {
                // Compare feature set with particular template.
                ver.Verify(FeatureSet, template, ref res);
                Data.IsFeatureSetMatched = res.Verified;
                Data.FalseAcceptRate = res.FARAchieved;
                if (res.Verified)
                    MessageBox.Show("Yes");
                break; // success
            }
        }

        if (!res.Verified)
            Status = DPFP.Gui.EventHandlerStatus.Failure;
        MessageBox.Show("No");

        Data.Update();
```

Comment: why arr.Length - 1?

Comment: There is no stream in the looping part

Comment: `MemoryStream` implements Disposable so should be wrapped in a `using` clause.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno, it has an index out of bounds error if I put in arr.Length

Comment: @MatNyaga it doesn't make so much sense, maybe you are missing something

Comment: @Dragonthoughts - that will have no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You unconditionally break from your loop, whether verified or not.

Your code should read :

```
  if (res.Verified) {
     MessageBox.Show("Yes");
     break; // success
  }
```

This is a good example why good coding practice suggests always having the brackets, even for a one line conditional effect, as the error would have been much more obvious.

Similarly you should have written

```
 if (!res.Verified) {
     Status = DPFP.Gui.EventHandlerStatus.Failure;
     MessageBox.Show("No");
 }
```

at the end of your snippet.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dragonthoughts, I made the following changes and the code works just fine:

```
for (int x = 0; x < (arr.Length - 1); x++)
        {
            byte[] fpbyte = GetStringToBytes(arr[x]);
            using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(fpbyte))
            {
                Data.Templates[x] = new DPFP.Template(stream);
                // Get template from storage.
                if (Data.Templates[x] != null)
                {
                    // Compare feature set with particular template.
                    ver.Verify(FeatureSet, Data.Templates[x], ref res);
                    Data.IsFeatureSetMatched = res.Verified;
                    Data.FalseAcceptRate = res.FARAchieved;
                    if (res.Verified)
                    {
                        status.Text = "Verified";
                        break; // success
                    }

                }


            }
        }
        if (!res.Verified)
        {
            Status = DPFP.Gui.EventHandlerStatus.Failure;
            status.Text = "Unverified";
        }
        Data.Update();
```